Lignin Test mechanism for amine identification

So, I've been trying to find a mechanism to explain the Lignin test for amine identification but haven't had any lucky so far. I was wondering if anyone here might know the mechanism? In the procedure I followed, we utilized only HCl, ethanol-dissolved amine, and a piece of paper. The expected result is the formation of a yellow precipitate on the paper. Initially, I considered the possibility of the Mannich reaction, but it requires formaldehyde, so that doesn't seem to be the case.

Can you add how did you search? Have you tried Google Scholar? Proper research starts from older literature may be starting from 1940s and working your way up. One can start from MOERKE, G. A. (1945). Lignin Color Reactions with Amino Compounds. The Journal of Organic Chemistry, 10(1), 42-45.
